# Administrator user receive Access Denied and Need Permission

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, permissions

I want to move a file that is named **resmon.exe** from `C:\Windows\System32` to `D:\`. While I logged with an *Administrator* user, but I can't move it and I receive something like **Access-Denied**!

As you see below I am Administrator :

[image]

This is output when I try to copy and paste normally :
When I right click and select paste :

[image]

When I click on *Continue* :

[image]

And this is output of Command-line windows, when I want to move the file via commands:

**Note: I run CMD as Administrator**

[image]

**Q1: Why I receive Access-Denied?**

**Q2: How can I move the file?**

**Q3 : What is *TrustedInstaller* in third image? AND how I can have its permission?**

Appreciate you time and consideration :)

Comment: It appears you are a local administrator not a domain administrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You receive access denied because `TrustedInstaller` is the owner of the file and this is a protected operating system file.
2. The steps needed involve taking ownership of the file, as detailed in this question: [how do i get administrative permission from trusted installer to delete a file in windows media player?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-do-i-get-administrative-permission-from/1a719aa0-c906-41ed-a80d-f3cd08889c6b)

   > **Before taking ownership I would suggest you to create a new restore point so that the system may be reverted back in case of any loss of data or irregular behavior.**
   >
   > 1. Locate the file or folder on which you want to take ownership in windows explorer
   > 2. Right click on file or folder and select “Properties” from Context Menu
   > 3. Click on Security tab
   > 4. Click on “Advance”
   > 5. Now click on Owner tab in Advance Security Settings for User windows
   > 6. Click on Edit Button and select user from given Change Owner to list if user or group is not in given list then, click on other users or groups. Enter name of user/group and click ok.
   > 7. Now select User/group and click apply and ok. (Check “Replace owner on sub containers and objects” if you have files and folder within selected folder)
   > 8. Click ok when Windows Security Prompt is displayed
   > 9. Now Owner name must have changed.
   > 10. Now click Ok to exist from Properties windows
3. `TrustedInstaller` is a special service that handles windows updates and owns many system files. [[Reference]What is TrustedInstaller service ?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c2fdddc9-f264-4bef-8c55-18306ae80d79/what-is-trustedinstaller-service-)